socket.io capturing compressed outbound messages
I'm trying to figure out how to log the bytes transferred out per socket for a socket.io 4 server for a long running message streaming application. I have perMessageDeflate enabled, and I'm able to log the onAnyOutbound messages, but none of them are compressed. Is there a way I can capture the actual payloads being sent after compression or at least get their size ? This would be on a per-message basis, not on disconnect.
